# cant call the jquery function to work in cakephp3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp

I cant call the jquery function below. I dont get an error but nothing happens. the code is in cakephp3 mvc where the jquery gets included automatically.   The jquery function to call works out the lat and long from an address given in cakephp3 form elements

```
  <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_street');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_suburb');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_postcode');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_state',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $auStates, 'default' => 'VIC'));
                    ?>
                    <hr>
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_lat',["value"=>0]);
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_long',["value"=>0]);
                    ?>

                     <input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate_address_lat_long" onClick="$(this).calculate_address_lat_long();" />

 /////////////   
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on('click', '#calculate_address_lat_long', function () {
        var address = '';
        address += $('#TutorAddressStreet').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#TutorAddressSuburb').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#TutorAddressPostcode').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#TutorAddressState').val();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $('#TutorAddressLat').val(latitude);
                $('#TutorAddressLong').val(longitude);
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + results[0].formatted_address + '</div>')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
            } else {
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-error">22Address Not Found</div>')
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have element with `id` as `calculate_address_lat_long`? Also check if jquery is getting loaded.

Comment: jqueruy is getting loaded but the line below isnt calling the function <input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate_address_lat_long" onClick="$(this).calculate_address_lat_long();" />

Comment: Id for 
`                   <input type="button" value="calculate" id="test" onClick="$(this).calculate_address_lat_long();" />` assigned is `test` and not `calculate_address_lat_long`

Comment: i changed this but it hasnt worked. I will update the OP

Comment: onClick="$(this).calculate_address_lat_long();" - remove it

Comment: ok but the function still doesnt get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onclick` -

`<input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate_address_lat_long" />`

or

Try this

```
  <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_street');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_suburb');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_postcode');
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_state',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $auStates, 'default' => 'VIC'));
                    ?>
                    <hr>
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_lat',["value"=>0]);
                    echo $this->Form->input('Tutors.address_long',["value"=>0]);
                    ?>

                     <input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate_address_lat_long" onClick="calculate_address_lat_long();" />


<script type="text/javascript">
     function calculate_address_lat_long() {
        var address = '';
        address += $('#TutorAddressStreet').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#TutorAddressSuburb').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#TutorAddressPostcode').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#TutorAddressState').val();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $('#TutorAddressLat').val(latitude);
                $('#TutorAddressLong').val(longitude);
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + results[0].formatted_address + '</div>')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
            } else {
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-error">22Address Not Found</div>')
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: no this didnt work. the function just isnt being called

Comment: in a function at first line add alert statement to check function is working or not

Comment: nope it doesnt work. This function just  cant get called in cakephp3 .

Comment: i think the problem is with the script itself so i will redo the question